# Expected Time Until Absorption and Variance of Time Until Absorption for absorbing transition matrix P, but with a Probability Vector u

Tags: discrete-mathematics, markov-chains

I didn't see this topic covered in the prompts.
I know how to find the fundamental matrix, N, of an absorbing transition matrix, P. This has also already been covered a lot in prior posts.
However, I'm having difficulty finding how to treat this when introducing a probability vector, u, for the starting state.
Would it simply be following the usual steps to find N, but using a canonical form of uP?

EDIT: If $u$ is instead a $nxn$ probability matrix, and $N$ is the $nxn$ fundamental matrix with $0$s for all absorbing states, then the Expected Time Until Absorption for each state can be found by $t^{u} = u \times N \times \textbf{1}$.
Typically (without a probability matrix), the Expected Time Until Absorption for each state is found by $t = N \times \textbf{1}$, and the Variance is found by $(2N - I) \times t - t_{sq}$, where $t_{sq}$ is each element of $t$ squared.
In an attempt to adjust the variance to account for the probability matrix $u$, I tried $(2u \times N - I) \times t^{u} - t^{u}_{sq}$. This is evidently not correct since there exists probability matrices $u$ such that $t^{u}_{sq}>(2u \times N - I) \times t^{u}$, leading to a negative variance. What would be the correct way to calculate variance in time until absorption adjusting for a probability matrix?

Comment: Ordinarily you find the expected absorption time, say $t(x)$, starting from each state $x$. Given an initial probability vector $u(x)$, you can reconstruct the expected absorption time from $t(x)$ by using the formula $\sum_x u(x) t(x)$. Or if you use the usual convention that probability vectors are row vectors and function vectors are column vectors, this is $ut$.

Comment: @Ian Thanks! that does make more sense. Clarifying question: would $u$ and $t$ have row/column length equal to the number of transient states?

Comment: You would usually have them encompass the entire state space, but $t(x)=0$ for all the absorbing states $x$, so only the component of $u$ concentrated on the transient states will actually contribute anything to the product.

Comment: @Ian If you have time, I ended up running into another issue while working on a problem. My first attempt didn't make sense. Please see my edits. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can find the variance in absorption time started from each state by only knowing the expected value of that absorption time. Can you give a reference for where you got $(2N-I)(t-t \cdot t)$ (where $\cdot$ is the elementwise product)? Also can you explain how this formula works with, for example, a deterministic process $A \to B \to C$?

Comment: Looks like in that case, following the notation of https://www.ssc.wisc.edu/~jmontgom/absorbingchains.pdf we have $P=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix},Q=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix},I-Q=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, and so $N=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: (Cont.) So here in that case I agree with you that $N \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ is the correct expected absorption time. But now $2N-I=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $t-t \cdot t=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -3 \end{bmatrix}$ which does not seem like it gives the right answer, so the product is $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -3 \end{bmatrix}$ which is clearly not the variance.

Comment: That being said, you can bootstrap the variance from scratch: $E[\tau^2 \mid X_0=x]$ is going to be $\sum_y E[(\tau+1)^2 \mid X_0=y] P(X_1=y \mid X_0=x)=\sum_y E[\tau^2 \mid X_0=y] P(X_1=y \mid X_0=x) + 2 \sum_y E[\tau \mid X_0=y] P(X_1=y \mid X_0=x) + 1$, unless $x$ is an absorbing state of course. You can solve this linear system and then do the subtraction to get the variance.

Comment: @Ian Thanks! I'll look more into bootstrapping the variance. The reference for the formula used is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain. "Variance on Number of Steps" just after Expected number of steps.

Comment: That will work fine then but it is different from what you said. (Also when I said bootstrapping earlier this was not w technical term.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your first question, given the expected time $t(x)$ to absorb starting from each state $x$ and the initial probability distribution $u(x)$, the expected time to absorb with this initial probability distribution is $\sum_x u(x) t(x)$. Normally we write distributions as row vectors and functions as column vectors; in this case this can be written as just $ut$. In terms of the fundamental matrix, $t=N \mathbf{1}$ so this is $uN\mathbf{1}$.

Regarding your question about the variance, here is a way to do it from scratch. You have the recursion:

$$E[\tau^2 \mid X_0=x]=\sum_y E[(\tau+1)^2 \mid X_0=y] P[X_1=y \mid X_0=x]$$

which expands to

$$E[\tau^2 \mid X_0=x]=\sum_y E[\tau^2 \mid X_0=y] P[X_1=y \mid X_0=x] + 2 \sum_y E[\tau \mid X_0=y] P[X_1=y \mid X_0=y] + 1.$$

Thus the conditional variance can be obtained as

$$V[\tau^2 \mid X_0=x]=\sum_y E[\tau^2 \mid X_0=y] P[X_1=y \mid X_0=x] + \sum_y E[\tau \mid X_0=y] P[X_1=y \mid X_0=y]$$

for each non-absorbing state $x$. This follows by looking at the recursion for the expectation:

$$E[\tau \mid X_0=x]=1 + \sum_y E[\tau \mid X_0=y] P[X_1=y \mid X_0=y]$$

and subtracting on both sides. In matrix notation you could write the equation for the variance as

$$v(x)=(P(v+t))(x)$$

for each non-absorbing state $x$ and $v(x)=0$ for the absorbing states. You can then again multiply out $uv$ if you have an initial probability distribution $u$.

Regarding your question about computing the variance using the fundamental matrix, I looked into this, and it can be done. But you need to be careful about the grouping. The variance started from each state is given by the column vector

$$(2N-I)t-(t \circ t)$$

where $\circ$ is the Hadamard product. You can multiply *that whole column vector* by $u$ on the left to get the variance of the absorption time for an initial probability distribution $u$. You do not replace $t$ by $ut$ everywhere in the identity above.

Comment: Functionally this is working just fine! Out of curiosity, do you have a citation for this? Only reason I had to ask on here is because I can't seem to find any books/papers addressing this exact problem. Once again, thanks for the help!

Comment: @R.Story For the first thing I just picked this up in coursework; it comes down to the total expectation formula in the end. Though various calculations like this are under the umbrella of "renewal theory".